# secure way to connect with remote Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-recommendation, remote

I created my application using MySQL and it relies completely on the database I have around 190 tables, and I'm afraid of security breaches and another problem is for remote access I have to add the IP addresses of the devices that would use it, and since they change dynamically I will need to regularly update the remote access IP addresses, what is a better option for the connection with the remote MySQL?  Currently I'm hosting it on my account at hostgator.

For now, the application is under a testing period so, I have time to change my approach with the database connection, It's a desktop application created using c# and visual studio 2013.

My question might seem silly but this is my first real life application so, I don't want to be a mess! 
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into SSL? You can also specify subnets when you grant privileges - i.e. GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO ''@'12.23.*.*'; i.e. select on any table in the mydb schema to any user from IP address 12.23.<whatever>.

Comment: @Vérace the problem is the ip addresses are dynamic, they change completely like sometimes they are 5.41.*.* and other times they are 95.*.*.* so, I don't know what I can do to solve this issue.

Comment: SSL can be used for the database itself?

Comment: See this [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-connections.html) about logging into MySQL using SSL. I'm more in the academic world myself, so security is a minor concern. Re. your variety of IP addresses - restrict as much as you can- you can issue two (or more) grants for the same user.

Comment: same here, my knowledge related to security is very small and this is my first application that people will actually use in the long term which is why I'm concerned

Comment: Thinking about this again, I have 1 suggestion. Allow root only access from 1 machine. Then, for your users (and where your system **might** be vulnerable), create audit tables (to which your users do **not** have access) and use triggers to create an audit trail of every INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. That way, even if your system is compromised (as Bruce Schneier says, security is a process, not a state - or as Rick James says down below - security is an "arms race") you will be able to figure out what happened and roll back any malicious changes. From what you have said, it's unlikely.

Comment: @Vérace thanks for the suggestion! I will do that and hope for the best! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the clients?  PHP?  Java?  (etc, etc)  There are potentially serious hacks that can do things like "SQL Injection" through them.  That is perhaps more common than IP restrictions.

Do you have `root` only from some secure place?  Does it have a hardened password?

Are all the application 'users' granted access only to the desired database, and with only the desired permissions?  And are all the passwords hardened?

Where are the client passwords?  Visible in code?  That is, if a hacker can get to the code, are the passwords a useless defense?

SSL is only one issue.  If your provider does not allow for SSL, see if someone else does.  If not, then consider hosting the servers yourself; it's cheaper in the long run, but much more work.  And it would solve the IP problem.

Check `skip_name_resolve`.

Comment: As I pointed out earlier, I'm using C# no php or java, and SQL injections won't be an issue I guess because the application will be used within a school and installed on 5-10 computers only and most of the users are noobs when it comes to programming and stuff like that. My main concern is outsiders those who know that this school has an application and might want to harm them. And yes the password of the database and username are all within the code itself but then again, the application will be installed in their desktops and the chances of hacking from within the institute are very small.

Comment: What do u mean by do u have root only? and I think hostgator does provide SSL.

Comment: `root` should have access to the database from as few places as possible.  Usually that means `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@localhost ...;` and nowhere else.  Then you harden the server to help prevent anyone from connecting as `root`.

Comment: @RickJames if I fix the root thing and the SSL I won't have anything else to worry about? Sometimes I just think about making all the pcs connect to one main pc which would stay open and online all the time and let the database be open there all the time. but then again they would need someone to start the local host for them and I think they don't have any IT expert over there

Comment: btw right now I have added the wild card %.%.%.% for the remote access just so they can test the application without problems related to the access. But I know this is very very bad! but for now it is ok coz there is no real data on the database

Comment: This question seems to me to be more about protecting application connectivity than it is about hardening the database. How do you perform admin tasks on the database?

Comment: by admin tasks you mean what exactly? creating new tables and such? I perform them by logging into my cpanel directly. The application is just used for the CRUD of data.

Comment: "I won't have anything else to worry about?" -- It's an arms race; there is no end.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need to use a DDNS service from a service such as [www.no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com), then filter on DDNS name.  The client will have to update their IP on the dynamic dns system though.

Have you considered running the db engine on a non standard port with very strong passwords and all the security best practices presented, then letting the clients connect that way?  You'll know if someone is really attempting to hack you if you see them attempting multiple or default passwords against your non standard port, that means they know it's a MySQL or some sort of DB back there.  You can log that info or even alert on it if you'd like.

Comment: How can I use a non standard port? www.no-ip.com is blocked in my area unfortunately.

Comment: heya bud, check out: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-default-mysql-port-under-linuxunix/

That should do it for you.  Any of the DynamicDNS providers will work for you, heck, you can even put it in your own local host file and reverse DNS.  That *should* work but I never tested it.

Comment: Using a non standard port is merely security through obscurity and, while it may deter the casual hacker, is not a good long term solution. Do you need to connect through the MySQL client? How does you app connect to the database?

Comment: @Vérace There are two ways in which I connect to the database one is through c# code that one is used for CRUD of the data and I have crystal reports in the application for them I have to connect through a mysql client on ODBC.

Comment: Well, then I humbly suggest that this is not the forum in which you should be asking your question. This is more about security in programming using the tools (C# and Crystal Reports) you have chosen, rather than being about securing your database. I think you should ask about this on Stack Overflow or C#/CR forums.

Comment: @Vérace just note that it's using filtering on DynamicDNS hostname *and* using a non default port.  This would fit many compliance requirements if a DB engine has a valid reason for being publicly accessible; and not going through some web/abstraction layer which is always the best case.  If the DB engine has to be publicly accessible, and it's not a heavily used machine, then a 'database firewall' will really give you the trifecta you need to be really tight.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options that help with security. A simple step is to not use the default 3306 port. Also, use very hardened passwords and if possible, change passwords often. A trick that I have done is instead of having your application communicate directly to your mysql server, have it communicate via PHP to an Apache server running on the same server as mysql. Then you can have the mysql port blocked and only accessible by Apache. Put Apache on a non-standard port and then have your program send your mysql query via post to Apache and then Apache can make the request to mysql via PHP. Make sure to keep your mysql user/pass that the PHP script uses in a folder that is not directly accessible by Apache in case your Apache server gets hacked.

Comment: Sounds interesting, Can you enlighten me more about this php and apache thing? I heard about using JSON and php for the database manipulation but I got scared from using it because these are going to be pages that are visible online to anyone who has the links or am I wrong about this? Sorry but I'm not a professional as I said this is my first real life project